# Is this a norm on $L^{p}([0,1])$?

Tags: proof-writing

Let $0< p< 1$ and let $\|f\| _{p}$ be defined as $(\int_{0}^{1} |f|^p)^{1/p}.$ Prove or disprove: $\|\cdot\|_{p}$ is a norm on $L^{p}([0,1])$

**My trial:**

It is a norm, but I am unable to prove the triangle inequality? Could anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a norm. Take $f=I_A, g=I_B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets of positive measures $a$ and $b$. Then $\|f+g\|_p =(a+b)^{1/p}$, $\|f\|_P =a^{1/p}$ and $\|g\|_P =b^{1/p}$ But $(a+b)^{1/p} \leq a^{1/p} +b^{1/p}$ is false. In fact $(a+b)^{1/p} > a^{1/p} +b^{1/p}$.

Comment: $I_{A}$ is the identity function on $A$ correct?

Comment: It is 1 on A and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: could you please tell me the details of calculating this $p-$norm please?

Comment: specially the $p-$norm of $f + g$

Comment: why are you taking $A$ and $B$ disjoint?

Comment: Also our $E$ is the interval [0,1] not $A$ or $B$, so why did you take $a, b$?

Comment: @Secretly $a$ and $b$ are not end points of the interval. They just any numbers between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: and why $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?

Comment: @Secretly I  cannot say $\|f+g\|_p=(a+b)^{1/p}$ if they are not disjoint.

Comment: So could you please tell me on which theorem you based your calculation for this step?

Comment: $\int |f+g|^{p}=\int_A |f+g|^{p}+\int_B |f+g|^{p}+\int_{(A\cup B )^{c}} |f+g|^{p}=a+b$